# Windows Get real letter assigned to a parition

Tags: windows, winpe

I'm using WinPe as a backup/restore method.
Using `dism` i capture/apply images to a parition.
The problem is when i want to apply/capture image to current partition... if i check diskpart had letter `C`(`systemdrive`) but when i enter in `WinPE` and check, will be another letter, `ex: G`.
I checked with `diskpart` and in windows has `C` letter but in WinPE will have `G` letter.
So exist any method to get the real letter assigned?
Thanks!

LE:
For info, I edit startnet.cmd with python in windows.

Comment: No, there is no way to tell what drive letter another instance of Windows will assign to a particular partition.  See if you can use the partition number instead, since that's fixed.  (You could probably use WMI or something to convert partition numbers to drive letters and back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `VolumeName` to apply a image (i checked and it's working):
Use `mountvol <drive> /L` and will return an addres like that `\\?\Volume{abd9ac7c-bea2-11e4-824b-806e6f6e6963}\` which will work on `dism /apply-image`.
More about `ountvol`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490934.aspx